# Programmatically disable auto-suggestions on Gboard

Tags: android, gboard

I'm trying to programmatically disable suggestions with `setInputType()` using `InputType TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`.

While this works for most keyboards, this doesn't work when using the "Gboard" keyboard; even with this input type, suggestions always appear. The problem is that the user can choose if he wants to have suggestions on input fields, regardless of the input type specified by the EditText.

How can the suggestions be suppressed for all keyboards, including Gboard?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution :

```
view.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

However you can see a little Font difference between an Input with suggestions and without.

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that a number bar appears above the characters.

Comment: Removing the `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` resolved the Font problem for me

Comment: Unfortunately, TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD means the user cannot switch to non-qwerty keyboards

Answer (score -2):

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputISD_Code"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen20"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:hint="@string/code"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Comment: This does not offer a solution to the question. Indeed, the `inputType` provided here is mentioned in it.